# Create Preview of Printed HTML Page

Tags: java, swing, html-rendering

I want to create a small preview of HTML that will be printed within a Swing app. Basically, it would display the page at the size of a PageFormat class (i.e. the size of a printable page), but at 1/4 the size or less of the page.

So far, I've tried the following:

```
    //Create components
    JDialog frame = new JDialog(new JFrame("Test"), "Test", true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.scale(0.5,0.5);
        super.paintComponent(g2);
    }};  
    PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension();
    dimension.setSize(pf.getImageableWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight());
    panel.setPreferredSize(dimension);

    panel.add(new JEditorPane("text/html", "<i>Testing, testing, one two three</i>"));

    //Finalize everything
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Unfortunately, this creates a JPanel that is the full page size, but scales the JEditorPane into the upper left quarter of the screen because the size of the JPanel doesn't seem to scale as well. Also, if you click on the JEditorPane, it appears at full size. How can I get the effect I want?

Also, this doesn't have to be an editable HTML page, so if there is some clever solution that doesn't involve directly displaying HTML, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html you can use the code to see how preview is implemeted.

Alternatively yu can define a `BufferedImage` passing desired width/height> Use the image's `getGraphics()` and apply the `AffineTransform` you need (scale in the simplest case). Then just call `yourJEditorPane.paint(g)` where g is the image's `Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setpreferredsize() try using setmaximumsize and instead of assigning
pf.getImageableWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight() directly, assign it to some int and try to print it. Then change the int according to the required size

Comment: Calling setMaximumSize() instead of setPreferredSize() shrinks the JPanel down to 4x the size of the JLabel. Calling both creates the same situation as described. I'm not sure why assigning pf.getImageableWidth() to an int (via `Double.inValue()`) would make any difference. Besides, the point is to create this preview before the item is actually printed.